# Apache throwing "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' "

Tags: php, mysql, apache, content-management-system

I was following this tutorial for creating a cms platform (`https://www.elated.com/articles/cms-in-an-afternoon-php-mysql/#step6`). I work on a mac, so I already had **apache** and **php**. I got the server running, but got the error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS) in /Users/liviarett/Documents/projects/cms-project/classes/Article.php on line 7.

So I thought I'd try **XAMPP** to see if it was something I had done wrong when setting everything up, but I got the exact same error.

Any ideas? The repo is here https://github.com/liviarett/cms-platform

Article.php starts with

```
<?php
 
/**
 * Class to handle articles
 */

class Article {
 
  // Properties
 
  /**
  * @var int The article ID from the database
  */
  public $id = null;
```

I don't think there's anything wrong with the code, since I copied and pasted it from the tutorial's instructions.

Comment: You should show us the code of Article.php. My guess is there is some syntax error there.

Comment: what code is on line 7 of Article.php?

Comment: Just edited the question! I don't think it's an issue with the code: class Article {
 
  // Properties
 
  /**
  * @var int The article ID from the database
  */
  public $id = null;

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a letter or any symbol in the lines before your **class** keyword.

check your code again or add a snapshot of your code so i can help you.

Answer (score 0):

i don't there's something wrong with the code, i have copied the exact same code from your repo in github and nothing went wrong, here's a screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpCHu.jpg

Comment: I don't think so either, I copied and pasted it from the tutorial, and no one else seems to be having this issue..

Comment: Seems you did not copy it correctly. I have raised a PR with the file updated.

Comment: Hi @ValerianPereira, thanks for these, it seems that my editor added these spaces! That error is gone, but now I'm getting a 'Sorry, a problem occurred. Please try later.' Do you have any quick ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Check what the exception message has to say.
Config file 

```
function handleException( $exception ) {
  echo "Sorry, a problem occurred. Please try later.";
  error_log( $exception->getMessage() );
}

@LiviaRett